# How to make a media player application for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, video-streaming

I don't have good idea about where to start. Any way, most of us have use a DVD player, what we do is to put an disc in that and it plays video(or Audio, but my concern is video). All controls like play pause, forward, rewind can be handled at DVD player end. With remote or buttons on the player. These effect reflect on TV screen.

Now, what I need to do is create a same application for iPhone. In that iPhone will be the DVD player and system monitor connected to that will behave like TV screen, all controls on iPhone screen will be equally effective on playing monitor. But my point is video content should be stream, not screen, of playing iPhone.

Please tell me from where should I start?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear.  You just want to mirror video to a TV?

Comment: Please don't be sorry, It's my fault if I am not clear, Any ways I don't want to mirror, I wanna send video stream, to monitor, from my iPhone. User may or may not play that on iPhone screen. but that should keep playing on system monitor.

Comment: OK, you want video on one screen (the TV) and other content (such as controls) on the iPhone?

Comment: I think you need AirPlay ....

Comment: @VakulSaini Any thing except that :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Airplay and an AppleTV as secondDisplay (DVD playingScreen) and specifying another external screen (video) than your internal one (control)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html